# How to make "What to expect" question constructive?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question was closed along with downvotes: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199257/what-level-of-queries-should-i-expect-from-an-interviewer-regarding-my-official

It contained the following text:

> Background:
>
> I have been working with a software company for some 5 years now. I haven't handled a "project" by myself yet. This is a robotics company and I am not a robotics person. So, the kind of work that I have handled so far are *"small"* C++ programming related stuffs in the projects.
>
> Tiny examples:
>   1. Someone has already made classes and written socket programming for this software X with UDP. My job was to add the TCP code using Qt API.
>   2. I had to add a "callback" functionality (using C++ templates) somewhere in the project for some reason.
>
> Another somewhat bigger example:
>   I had to set up a functionality of message exchanging between two components (according to protocol given) in C++.
>
> Both these example tasks are related to the "proprietary" software of this company.
>
> ***What kind of questions (in which depth) should I expect the interviewer to ask regarding these example tasks?***

These questions aren't closed:

[What should a C++ developer expect on an interview at a Rails company?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49845/what-should-a-c-developer-expect-on-an-interview-at-a-rails-company?rq=1)

[What should I expect from a technical evaluation for C++?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105494/what-should-i-expect-from-a-technical-evaluation-for-c?rq=1)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70251/what-should-i-expect-as-a-c-software-engineer-in-a-company-that-develops-pytho?rq=1

**How is my question different from them, and what should be done to improve it?**

Comment: for the sake of precision, your question has been closed as **not constructive**, not as off-topic. I for one believe it's perfectly on topic, and I would not vote close on that ground, as opposed to NC.

Comment: @gnat So, in what way is that non-constructive? Please explain how to make it constructive.

Comment: my take on it is explained in [another answer here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5226/31260), regarding a similar question that has been closed as NC

Comment: I voted to close all three of your example questions as "Not Constructive."  I don't think it's possible to make them constructive; every employer is different, and any attempt at answering them amounts to speculation.

Answer (score 2):

I voted to close as not a real question, you give a big back story and then ask a very open ended and vague question that has very different answers depending on what you are actually interviewing for.

The other questions are all old ones that haven't had any real maintenance to them and may need to also be closed, sites change over time and different questions become acceptable or unacceptable and the old questions rarely get any views to really justify cleaning all of them up.

Comment: Your answer is not helpful. Since people have voted to close so it is very obvious that they have found the question vague. In this thread I wish to understand how to make it specific. You said: `then ask a very open ended and vague question that has very different answers depending on what you are actually interviewing for.` I asked specifically regarding the official tasks on my resume. How much can the interviewer go in depth in inquiring about them. How is this a vague question and how should it be mended?

Comment: @user462608 because an interviewer for an entry level programming job asks very different questions than a senior level or architect or team lead position

Comment: Anyways, If I mention the post I am applying for, will that help?

Comment: yes that would help, narrowing the scope of your question would be beneficial, that is the heart of the problem I expressed.

Comment: Ok, I will repost the same question with this change added.